# Nested loops shortcut in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In a program I'm writing I have a multidimensional array and I need to perform some operation only on the most inner objects.

Is there any better way to write this code?

```
for (const threeDimensionalArray of fourDimensionalArray) {
  for (const twoDimensionalArray of threeDimensionalArray) {
    for (const oneDimensionalArray of twoDimensionalArray) {
      for (const obj of oneDimensionalArray) {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Something like:

```
for (const obj someSpecialKeyword fourDimensionalArray) {
  // do something
}
```

Note: I know of one solution which is using a flattening function. The problem with using a flattening function is that this iteration is going to be used a lot in the program so I am worried about the performance. Even if I save this multidimensional array in two formats (a flat one and a multidimensional one) it can cause performance issues because this array is also changed a lot and also makes the code longer.

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: What is the actual structure (i.e. formal data-type) of the array? I assume it's a jagged array (as JavaScript doesn't support true multidimensional arrays).

Comment: Have you considered writing an iterator function?

Comment: The most inner type is an object with attributes

Comment: A `flatMap` function is what I would use and then iterate over all elements, if performance is key...  are you sure you want to solve this problem with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

> I know of one solution which is using a flattening function

I assume by "flattening function" you mean a Reducer function? (It is unfortunate that JavaScript's `Array.prototype` functions, such as `reduce`, `map`, `filter`, etc perform full copies on every step).

[An alternative is to write a Generator Function (aka Iterator Function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```
function* getAll( fourDimensionalArray ) { // The asterisk is not a typo.
    for (const threeDimensionalArray of fourDimensionalArray) {
        for (const twoDimensionalArray of threeDimensionalArray) {
            for (const oneDimensionalArray of twoDimensionalArray) {
                for (const obj of oneDimensionalArray) {
                    yield obj;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
for( const item of getAll( fourDimensionalArray ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Generator functions are very efficient and do not cause an array copy operation.

Comment: thanks to you I have learned something new today; have my upvote

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive function which take an array or item and a callback for non arrays.

This function does not rely on a fixed structure.

```
function iter(value, cb) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for (const item of value) iter(item, cb);
    } else {
        cb(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider `const arr = []; arr.push( arr ); iter( arr, console.log );`

Comment: "this array has no floor" - I'm unfamiliar with the term "floor" in the context of arrays - can you explain? My point was that your function is vulnerable to a stack-overflow when dealing with a cyclical object-graph.

Comment: in technical terms, the array has a circular reference and is not able to get the final item of the array.